# Perfect shuffle of 52 cards

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, card-games

Prove: How many perfect shuffles of a deck of 52 cards do you need to do until the deck returns to its original order?

Can anyone please help me prove this?

Attempt: I have tried putting the deck of cards as a 2 line permutation .

(1 2 3 4 .....52) then by shuffling the first time, card 2 will be in position 1 and card 27 will be in position 1. So, (2 4 6 8 ......1 3 ......51).  However, I don't know how to prove this.

Thank you.

Comment: I think after four times it has to return to its original position.  I didn't calculate it but my feelings say so. Maybe its wrong who knows.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a [faro shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faro_shuffle).  It restores the original order in either 8 or 52 iterations, depending on whether the cards are permuted in the order [1, 27, 2, 28, ... 26, 52] or [27, 1, 28, 2, ..., 52, 26].

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do a "perfect" riffle shuffle.  Label the initial cards as 
$1,2,3,\ldots,52$.  First you split the deck into equal piles: $1,2,3,\ldots,26$ and 
$27,28,29,\ldots,52$.  Then you interleave them: but which goes first?
One way is $1,27,2,28,\ldots,26,52$.  The other way is $27,1,28,2,\ldots,52,26$.